# Strange Simultaneous Equations

Tags: equation-solving

Solve the simultaneous equations:

70-T=7a

T-40=4a

By multiplying both sides of the equations by a factor and shifting the terms I transformed them into the following form:

-28a-4T=-280

-28a+7T=+280

Further simplification results in a single equation as follows:

-11T=-560

So, `T` is a recurring number, which I know cannot be correct, so where am I going wrong?

Comment: So this will get removed because it has nothing to do with the software Mathematica, it's just a math question.  That being said, you did everything right up to the end, and you just need to take it a step further to get that `T=560/11`.  Then substitute this into either of the first two equations to solve for `a`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics and not about the software system *Mathematica*.

Comment: could we get this question moved to the mathematics site?

Comment: @DarthVader, actually if you'll check my comment and Inari's answer below, there isn't any need to move this question.  You have your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a bit startled as to your question. This is a system of linear equations, two equations, two variables, thus if there is a solution, there is one unique one. This you have found, as T = 560/11 -> a = 30/11. This is all, is it not?

Comment: I think, upon 2nd thought, that the solution does not need to be unique, but well ... in this case it is :D It'd depend on wheter the determinant of the matrix is unequal zero in general ... but that's maybe thinking too much for this simple problem.